# SQL query to build calculated field using Logic while selecting rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a temporary table with some values as mentioned below.

| ID | Date | st | Time | Rk |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| E1 | 1-1-23 | A | 8:10 | 1 |
| E1 | 1-1-23 | A | 8:15 | 2 |
| E1 | 1-1-23 | A | 8:20 | 3 |
| E1 | 1-1-23 | A | 8:12 | 1 |
| E1 | 1-1-23 | A | 8:16 | 2 |

Using a SQL Server query I would like to generate the below output. I can not use Cursor or Loop. Please guide on how to achieve this.

| ID | Date | st | Time | Rk | Tag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| E1 | 1-1-23 | A | 8:10 | 1 | 1 |
| E1 | 1-1-23 | A | 8:15 | 2 | 1 |
| E1 | 1-1-23 | A | 8:20 | 3 | 1 |
| E1 | 1-1-23 | A | 8:12 | 1 | 2 |
| E1 | 1-1-23 | A | 8:16 | 2 | 2 |

I have tried using the case expression but I am unable to store the value and can't set variable value in SQL query while selecting the rows.

Comment: What's the required logic? Just return all columns as they are and add another one named "tag" that will always be counted up when the value in column Rk is 1?

Comment: It is required to counted up whenever the Rk is 1. But how to do that without using loops or cursor.

Comment: Why the restriction on no cursors or loops? Please show us what you tried. If you add DDL+DML for your sample data you make it much easier for people to assist. It appears you have a simple gaps-and-islands problem (which you can research).

Comment: You also don't have a column to order by... since the times overlap... for example what rk=3 appear in the middle of your results rather than at the end, which it would it sorted by time.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very clear of the logic, but this may work.

```
SELECT *
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID, [Date], St, Rk ORDER BY [Time]) AS rn
FROM #SomeTable
```

Sample:

```
with cte as (
select 'e1' as id, 1 as st, 1 as t, 1 as rk
union all
select 'e1' as id, 1 as st, 5 as t, 2 as rk
union all
select 'e1' as id, 1 as st, 10 as t, 3 as rk
union all
select 'e1' as id, 1 as st, 4 as t, 1 as rk
union all
select 'e1' as id, 1 as st, 6 as t, 2 as rk
)
select * 
, row_number() over(partition by id, st, rk order by t) as tag
from cte
order by tag, rk
```

Comment: Partition by "rk" isn't going to work, OP wants the counter to increase each time rk resets to 1.

Comment: OK partitioning by rk will work, so long as there are the same number of rows per group, but if it was 1,2,3-1,2-1,2,3 then it wouldn't. But of course we don't actually have anything to order the rows by, so needs clarification from OP.

Comment: I have used DENSE_RANK to get the desired result . However, there is more to do with it.